# CMake library file missing

Tags: cmake

I'm currently struggling with cmake.

I'm using Cmake for an embedded platform with GCC.

My project is separate into several modules. Each module is build into a static library. At link time, all of these libraries are collected and linked into one binary.

The problem: I created a new folder for some unit tests. All sources are build into a library libunit_tests.a.(I checked the library actually gets created).

However in my linker call other libraries are passed to the linker, mine however gets omitted resulting in an undefined reference error.

My folder structure looks like this

*
unit_tests/

*
unit_tests/inc

*unit_tests/src

There is one Cmake file located at
- /unit_tests/CMakeLists.txt

My actual CMakeLists.txt file is pretty basic

```
include_directories("./inc")
set(module_name "unit_tests")

set(MODULE_SOURCES 
    ./inc/active_tests.h
    ./inc/Run_All_Tests.h ./src/Run_All_Tests.c
)

###########################
# add library
###########################
if(MODULE_SOURCES)

    # add files to library
    add_library("${module_name}"
                ${MODULE_SOURCES}) 

    target_link_libraries("${module_name}"
                           -Wl,--start-group
                           -Wl,--end-group)

endif()
```

How do i pass this library to the linker to resolve the undefined reference error?

I thought this is done via add_libary and target_link_libraries?

Comment: I think you forgot to link some libraries to your "unit_test" module. The `target_link_libraries` should also contains other cmake libraries that are used in your unit tests.

Comment: "I thought this is done via add_libary and target_link_libraries?" - Yes, in CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` call. Please, prepare [mcve] and show **exact error messages** which it produces. Currently it is unclear where and how do you use `unit_tests` library and what errors you got.